# App crashing with no debug error - Doesn't look like a memory issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm having problems with my app crashing with no errors and nothing being caught by the debugger. I've checked memory usage and it stays steady at around 3MB. I receive a memory warning, but it doesn't happen when theres a spike in the amount of memory my application is using.

Comment: i am facing sometimes the same situation like you. i am using CritterCism for getting Crash reports, and if the debugger puts no errors, then i am getting it from CritterCism. Maybe that could help you to use a crashreporter: https://www.crittercism.com/

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876874/how-to-track-crash-in-ios5/10876899#10876899

Comment: I' using a crash reporter already called BugSense. The app crashes and it doesn't report the error. I presume its crashing before it get around to reporting the bug

Comment: @NaveenThunga I've enabled that already. I've also checked that breakpoints are enabled and working by setting on elsewhere in the app

Comment: its better to check all variables either you deallocated or not

Comment: @Matto Delete app from the Simulator and restart your XCode. If possible restart machine too. Then try to install the build. God knows it might work. :)